# How to identify the largest values with a double filter in group_by() using R

Tags: r, group-by, formattable

I have a data.frame with lots of basin data over the years.

I would like to identify the highest value of each class using a `group_by` filter, but which preserves the source basin and year information.

For example, which basin has the highest `veg` value for the year 2005? and for the year 2006?....
The same for the `grass` class: which is the basin with the highest value for grass in 2005 and 2006.

I thought about using the formmattable for a visual inspection, but it does this min/max analysis disregarding the age group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

df<-read.table(text="basin  year    veg wet crop    grass   urb water   soil
01  2005    52.64   0   1197.98 524.56  0   0   2.25
01  2009    54.14   0   1171.7  550.51  0   0   1.08
09  2008    9271.08 0   41.66   22190.32    0   5.82    37.34
11  2013    29460.53    0   16489.56    71927.62    437.41  33.1    56.96
04  2017    30831.06    0   5713.81 73876.6 156.75  103.7   29.69
01  2006    47.376  0   1078.182    472.104 0   0   2.025
01  2010    48.726  0   1054.53 495.459 0   0   0.972
09  2009    8343.972    0   37.494  19971.288   0   5.238   33.606
11  2014    26514.477   0   14840.604   64734.858   393.669 29.79   51.264
04  2018    27747.954   0   5142.429    66488.94    141.075 93.33   26.721
01  2007    42.6384 0   970.3638    424.8936    0   0   1.8225
01  2011    43.8534 0   949.077 445.9131    0   0   0.8748
09  2010    7509.5748   0   33.7446 17974.1592  0   4.7142  30.2454
11  2015    23863.0293  0   13356.5436  58261.3722  354.3021    26.811  46.1376
04  2019    24973.1586  0   4628.1861   59840.046   126.9675    83.997  24.0489
05  2005    52.14   0   1169.7  548.51  0   0   0.92
", sep="", header=TRUE)

df%>%
  group_by(year, basin)%>%
  summarise(across('veg':'soil'), max)
```

try2

```
library(formattable)
#Formatar a tabela
formattable(df, list(
  'veg' = color_tile("#ccf0f0","#0066cc"),
  'wet' = color_tile("#ccf0f0","#0066cc"),
  'crop' = color_tile("#ccf0f0","#0066cc"),
  'grass' = color_tile("#ccf0f0","#0066cc"),
  'urb' = color_tile("#ccf0f0","#0066cc"),
  'water' = color_tile("#ccf0f0","#0066cc"),
  'soil'= color_tile("#ccf0f0","#0066cc")
  ))
```

with `formattable` I can see the highest values by the strongest colors, but `formattable` cannot group by year.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way, a `dplyr` solution.

### `dplyr`.

This solution uses `slice_max` to keep the `n = 2` greatest values per column.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(basin) %>%
  summarise(across(veg:soil, \(x) tail(sort(x), n = 2)))
```

Comment: I tried to apply the method, but I couldn't. Because my df had 16 lines, after the process it continues with 16 lines and did not identify the highest values.

Comment: @wesleysc352 See if it is corrected now.